# Correct regex expression for a specific page

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for regex expression for following url

```
http://www.roots.com/buffer/index.html?http://www.menetwork.com/tv_shows/roots/video/index.html
```

Any help will be appericiated

Comment: Did you tried something ? And what do you want to match/catch or replace ?

Comment: Why regex? String equality would be the appropriate test. If you need regex, where are you stuck?

Comment: String equality is not allowed in particular project i am working on.

Comment: Okay, so where are you stuck? What part are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Read up on regular expressions either [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1) *(clear as mud)* or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) *(better)* and/or experiment/read up on sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

In this case, to match *exactly* that string, you want a "start of input" anchor (`^`) at the beginning, an "end of input" anchor (`$`) at the end, and your string exactly in the middle with any characters that are special to regular expressions escaped with a backslash. So:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.roots\.com\/buffer\/index\.html\?http:\/\/www\.menetwork\.com\/tv_shows\/roots\/video\/index.html$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/\bhttp:\/\/www\.roots\.com\/buffer\/index\.html\?http:\/\/www\.menetwork\.com\/tv_shows\/roots\/video\/index\.html\b/
```

To match this url you need to escape all:

```
/ with \/
? with \?
. with \.
```

Then put the escaped url in a word boundary: `\bEscapedURL\b`.
Now tell JavaScript, that this is a regular expression by wrapping: /regex/

Now you can use it as follows:

---

```
if (/\bhttp:\/\/www\.roots\.com\/buffer\/index\.html\?http:\/\/www\.menetwork\.com\/tv_shows\/roots\/video\/index\.html\b/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
// Match attempt failed
}
```